# I want to chenge fetch data result in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Something wrong in my query

Currently get result like that :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = 1 ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id)] => 494 ) )
```

I want : `494`

My table :

**sms_history table**
[image]
**sms table**
[image]
**users table**
[image]

My code :

Controller :

```
 $total_available = $this->Dashboard_m->get_total_available_sms();
 print_r($total_available);
```

Model :

```
public function get_total_available_sms()
{

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT ( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = 1 ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id) FROM sms_history JOIN sms ON sms_history.clinic_id= sms.clinic_id');

return $query->result(); 

}
```

Comment: use `return $query->result_array();` and please show the result.  `SELECT (( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = 1 ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id)) AS num FROM sms_history JOIN sms ON sms_history.clinic_id= sms.clinic_id` Use this query.

Comment: it's not working for get `494` result

Comment: After using result_array() function, can you access $total_available['num'] ?

Comment: thanks now result get like that : `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [num] => 494 ) )`

Comment: Seems like you are using the result() function which returns an object. You can access using `$total_available->num`. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query: `SELECT (( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = 1 ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id)) AS num FROM sms_history JOIN sms ON sms_history.clinic_id= sms.clinic_id`

So you can access using the 'num' index.
You can either use the result() or result_array() function and use the 'num' index accordingly. Thank You.